# how to create the sqlite database without Android Studio and then import that database into the android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to create a database without using android studio means like a MySQL. 
After creating that database, can I import that database into my android studio, please can any one suggest me related answer to this.

Comment: You can put a sqlite db in raw and copy it to right place after app is started.I prefer to create database in android and  use sql to insert data.

Comment: which software should I use to create the database

Comment: navicat (http://www.navicat.com/cht/).